# Docker file not found error inside the container to create a new image

Tags: docker

I need to create a container for which I'm able to create new images.
My first guest was to run docker on docker but found that the right 
way to do this was using the --privileged argument so the container 
has access to the docker daemon.

For this I'm runnin the following comand:

```
docker run --privileged  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/user/container_data:/app/app -d -p 5100:5100 mcf2:latest
```

I'm using ***-v /home/user/container_data:/app/app*** because I'm creating the folder for the new images from
templates for flask apps and saving them on that directory.

One of the files I'm creating from the templates is 'create_image.sh' which has the docker build statement E.G.

```
'docker build -t new_container:latest .'
```

for that I'm running the following code inside the running container:

```
bash_path= 'app/classification_model/create_image.sh'
subprocess.call([bash_path],shell=True)
```

But I always get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: app/model/create_image.sh: docker: not found
```

But the file does exist, if do ls in the container 'app/' is in the list of folders
I have also checked  the bind directory and

```
'/home/user/container_data/classification_model/create_image.sh'
```

Does exist.

I have tried changing bash_path to

```
bash_path= '/app/classification_model/create_image.sh'
```

and

```
bash_path= '/app/app/classification_model/create_image.sh'
```

But get the same error for all the cases

**EDIT: **

I have changed the Docker file to:

```
From docker:dind
FROM ubuntu:18.04 



RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
...
...
```

And run again:

```
docker run --privileged  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/user/container_data:/app/app -d -p 5100:5100 mcf2:latest
```

I'm still getting the same error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two thing

1. Docker in Docker
2. Docker in Docker with host Docker Socket

In the both cases, Docker should be installed in the container, it does not mean by mounting `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` this any container will able to launch or run docker command.

1. In the first option, it will start containers as a child container.
2. In the second option, the container will have access to the Docker socket, and will, therefore, be able to start containers. Except that instead of starting **“child”** containers, it will start **“sibling”** containers.

**updated:**
Docker offical dind image is alpine based so you can install using `apk` instead of `apt`.

```
FROM docker:dind

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 python3-dev
```

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages

Comment: I update the question, Is that correct? Still getting the same error.

Comment: no, there must be only one base image. so remove `From ubuntu:18.04 `

Comment: How can I get linux over that layer? I'm getting this error:  ---> Running in 6843a35cd498
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Comment: let me verify the base image